# Query to select subcategories of categories of destinations which are active?

Tags: sql, mysql, join

I have a table of destinations ( states ) which contain primary level categories and subcategories for activities. My ultimate goal is to output xml navigation links so I can link to:

1. Each destination permalink ( ordered alphabetically by destination slug name )
2. Each category underneath
3. Each subcategories underneath the category

**The below is what I'll generate with the sql query, incase it has any bearing on the query but I don't need xml help for this question**:

```
<item href="/destinations/alabama/">
    <list>
        <item href="/destinations/alabama/category/">
            <list>
               <item href="/destinations/alabama/category/sub-category/"></item>
            </list>
        </item>
    </list>
</item>
<item href="/destinations/maryland/">
    <list>
        <item href="/destinations/maryland/category/">
            <list>
               <item href="/destinations/maryland/category/sub-category/"></item>
            </list>
        </item>
    </list>
</item>
```

Currently I have a query that grabs subcategories but it doesn't account for active destinations.

```
SELECT

subcategories.name AS subcategory_name,
subcategories.slug AS subcategory_slug,
categories.name AS category_name,
categories.slug AS category_slug

FROM

subcategories

LEFT JOIN destinations_subcategories ON
destinations_subcategories.subcategory_id = subcategories.id

LEFT JOIN categories ON
destinations_subcategories.category_id = categories.id

WHERE
1=1 AND
subcategories.is_active = 1 AND
categories.is_active = 1
```

Which returns:

```
subcategory_name    subcategory_slug    category_name    category_slug
Fly Fishing         fly-fishing         Fishing          fishing
```

But this query doesn't account for destinations which are active, since it's possible to map relationships between inactive destinations and active categories. I'm thinking I need to maybe have a subquery grabbing all active destinations, then do the joining?

SCHEMA/row samples:

```
id    name       slug       active
7     Maryland   maryland   1
```

My categories table, sample row:

```
id    name       slug       active
1     Fishing    fishing    1
```

Subcategories table sample row:

```
id    name           slug           active
3     Fly-Fishing    fly-fishing    1
```

And 2 tables to store relationships, the first maps subcategories to categories:

```
id    category_id    subcategory_id
5     1              3
```

The second, `destinations_subcategories` maps destinations to subcategories:

```
id    destination_id   category_id    subcategory_id
5     7                1              3
```

Comment: doesn't mysql determine the optimal join order? (not too sure if it holds good with the standard sql syntax though)
if you do a select foo from a, b, c where bar and baz and zee
mysql would determine the join order based on the stat estimates it has.

Comment: I mean syntactically, how would I go about modifying this query so it takes the active destinations into account? I updated the question title.

Comment: mysql does determine the optimal join order

Answer (score 1, accepted):

how about this

```
SELECT

subcategories.name AS subcategory_name,
subcategories.slug AS subcategory_slug,
categories.name AS category_name,
categories.slug AS category_slug

FROM

destination 

INNER JOIN destinations_subcategories on destination.id = destinations_subcategories.destination_id and destination.active = 1

LEFT JOIN subcategories ON destinations_subcategories.subcategory_id = subcategories.id

LEFT JOIN categories ON destinations_subcategories.category_id = categories.id

WHERE 1=1 
AND subcategories.is_active = 1 
AND categories.is_active = 1
```

This would make sure that only active destinations are shown

Comment: Ya thanks, I guess I had a mental lapse or something from not SQLing in a while. Kept overthinking the problem.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT destination.name , categories.name, sub-category.name 
FROM
destination_subcategories as ds, destinations, categories,  subcategories 
WHERE
ds.destination_id = destination.id and ds.catrgoy_id = category.id and ds.sub_category_id = sub_category.id and destination.is_active = 1 and categories.is_active = 1 and subcategory.is_active = 1;
```

This looks like should work unless, i've misunderstood the schema.